# Origin of "idiocracy"

Tags: etymology, neologisms

Did the word "idiocracy" exist prior to the release of the [movie of the same title](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/), or is it a neologism coined by its screenwriters?

Comment: If you look at Ngram, the term goes back 200 years, with changing meanings.  It's hard to tell from context in many cases, but the term was definitely used in the sarcastic sense prior to the movie.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interestingly, the word already existed as far back as 1681, and [originally meant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Idiocracy):

> Peculiarity of constitution; that
>   temperament, or state of constitution,
>   which is peculiar to a person;
>   idiosyncrasy.

So it was basically an alternative form to "idiosyncrasy" and was just re-appropriated for its other meaning.

However, even more interestingly, I see a reference from the OED to the use of this word with the current interpretation of "idiot form of government" (made by an author named Thomas Sinclair) from all the way back in 1878 (and my sincere apology for the unfortunate fact that the cited quotation is antisemitic):

> No Jew of them all would..set up a
>   theocracy, or *idiocracy, for this is
>   the exact word, more eagerly and
>   remorselessly.

Great question; I was surprised by what I discovered.

Comment: The original use you cite makes sense if you know the origin of the word "idiot". In Ancient Greek, `idiṓtēs` means "private citizen", which contrasts with something public or shared, with no (direct) implication of stupidity. Though most likely the screenwriter thought of the government of a state ruled by fools, which I think is a banal use of the word.

Comment: Actually, the part that I found interesting was the fact that the original use of the word had no connection to a form of government.  The *-cracy* in the old "idiocracy" therefore came from the Greek *krasis* (mixture) rather than *kratos* (rule, strength). To add another interesting fact about *idio-*, we also get the linguistic term "idiolect" from that same root, and it means, a way of speaking particular to the individual -- like the way you might speak to your cat or your significant other. (Really just a lot of interesting things about this word!)

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Idiocracy) reports the words derives from *idio-*, and a word that is mixture of French, and Greek.

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* reports that *idio-* means "distinct, private, personal, own"; its origin is from Greek *idios* (own, distinct).

Answer (score 1):

The term derives from two Greek words:

**Idiotis**, which means private person and in ancient Greek had a negative connotation as a selfish individual that does not care about the common matters and the collective good.

**Kratos**, which means power, rule, dominance (Similar to democracy power of the demos/people)

These two words together basically mean: **"The rule of the idiots"**

Comment: This explains what the word means but doesn't address the question which was about the word's origin in English.

Answer (score 0):

I was sure that one of the men present when America was establishing itself as a democracy said such a system could only result in an idiocracy. That celebrity and  popularity would become the criteria for presidents and this would be disastrous. Whoever it was had very little regard for the general populous, thinking them unworthy of a vote equal to that of one of the ruling class. Good prediction for maybe the wrong reasons. Hopefully I'll be back to cite the quote and name the author.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to find the alleged quote with [Founders Online](https://founders.archives.gov/index.xqy) but came up with nothing even with wildcard searches.

Answer (score -5):

It is a combination of *idiot* and *democracy*, and meant to refer to a democracy of idiots.  There are similar examples like *meritocracy* (a democracy based on merit) or *autocracy*.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but you were likely dv'ed b/c the question was about prior origins beyond the simple combination of the two words.

Comment: Also, I would want to see some supporting evidence for the claim that it is based on "democracy". "Autocracy" is certainly an independent formation, and I believe that "meritocracy" is as well.
It's quite possible that the coiners of the word for the film had "democracy" in mind, but it's equally possible that they were just basing it on the range of "-cracy" words.

Comment: @Colin: you are correct. The ending *-cracy* or *-crasy* comes from Greek *kratia*, which means *power*. The word *demo* comes from Greek *demos*, meaning *the people*, giving us *power of the people* for the word *democracy*. The same applies to *meritocracy*, which has nothing to do with *democracy*, and *idiosyncrasy* (Greek *idiosunkrasia*). PS: I'm not 100% certain of the transliteration from Greek (I'm not native English), but the meanings are correct. See also the note of Kosmonaut under the answer above.